# Saving a file to a location with special characters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, special-characters, saving-data

I'm currently having difficulties saving my data frame to an excel file in a certain location because the location contains a special character (ø).

I'm trying the following:

`df1.to_excel(r"C:\Users\ps\Ø\M O - PS\NL.xlsx")`, but it's giving me the following error: SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file C:/Users/ps/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/main.py on line 53, but no encoding declared.

I then tried declaring the encoding as follows: # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-, but doing so proceed to give me the following error message: xlsxwriter.exceptions.FileCreateError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\ps\\xc3\x98\M O - PS\NL.xlsx'

I am using Pycharm community edition 2020.2.2.

Comment: "but it's giving me the Non-ASCII character error." What error is it giving you *exactly*?

Comment: …and **what's** giving it to you?

Comment: I have updated the question with the specific error message.

Comment: Python 2? You need to declare the encoding of the source file if you use non-ASCII characters with a special comment at the top: `#coding=utf8` for example.

Comment: Yes, it seems I'm getting a different error message now I have declared the encoding at the top, but it seems it's telling me that the location I have defined doesn't exist. I have updated the question with the error message.